# Laravel pass value to model

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I try this query with eloquent:

```
'MentorId'  => $employee->intern(true)->mentor(true)->MentorId,
```

And in my `employee` and `intern` model I've got this:

**Intern**

```
  /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function intern($withTrashed = false)
    {
        if($withTrashed == true)
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(internModel::class, 'InternId')->withTrashed();
        }

        return $this->belongsTo(internModel::class,'InternId');
    }
```

**Mentor**

```
 /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function mentor($withTrashed = false)
    {
        if($withTrashed == true)
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(mentorModel::class, 'MentorId')->withTrashed();
        }

        return $this->belongsTo(mentorModel::class,'MentorId');
    }
```

But it crashes:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2148:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mentor()
```

How could I fix this?

--EDIT--

**Employee**

```
<?php

namespace App\src\employee;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\src\department\Department as departmentModel;
use App\src\employee\Employee as employeeModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\src\intern\Intern as internModel;
use App\src\mentor\Mentor as mentorModel;
use App\src\employee\Role as roleModel;

class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use EmployeeServiceTrait;

    /**
     * table name
     */
    protected $table = 'employee';

    /**
     * Mass assignment fields
     */
    protected $fillable = ['RoleId', 'DepartmentId', 'InternId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Bio','api_token', 'email', 'LinkedIn', 'password', 'Address', 'Zip', 'City', 'ProfilePicture', 'BirthDate', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Suspended','LinkedIn'];

    /**
     * Primarykey
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'EmployeeId';

    /**
     * Deleted_at
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(roleModel::class,'RoleId');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function intern($withTrashed = false)
    {
        if($withTrashed == true)
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(internModel::class, 'InternId')->withTrashed();
        }

        return $this->belongsTo(internModel::class,'InternId');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(departmentModel::class,'DepartmentId');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function mentor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(mentorModel::class,'MentorId');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(employeeModel::class,departmentModel::class,'CompanyId','DepartmentId');
    }

    /**
     * @param $role
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if(strtolower($this->role->RoleName) == strtolower($role))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the relationships mapped out in your Employee model?

Comment: @Frisbetarian what do you mean?

Comment: You need to define the relationships that Employee has with Mentor and Intern.

Comment: The method `intern()` must be specified in the `Employee` model, while the `mentor()` method has to be in the `Intern` model

Comment: Edit your question to include Employee.

Comment: @all please see my edit!

Comment: What happens when you change the relationships in Employee to belongsToMany?

Comment: When I change Intern in employee to belongsToMany I receive the same error.

Comment: @Frisbetarian also the same.

Comment: @jamie which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Do you have a method called 'mentor' on your `internModel`? because to me it looks like your Intern model has an intern method (which should be the other way around?); unless your question is worded incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that any Eloquent relationship object is actually an instance of [`Relation`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php).  This means when you create relationships you actually return a collection (instance of `Builder`); Hense your error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2148:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mentor()

The simple solution, without any modification to your code would be something like:

```
'MentorId'  => $employee->intern(true)->first()->mentor(true)->first()->MentorId;
```

However, you could use overloading like the following:

```
'MentorId'  => $employee->intern->mentor->MentorId;
```

Although this will *NOT* include your `withTrashed`.  You can however tweak your relationship to something like:

```
public function intern($withTrashed = false)
{
    $relation = $this->belongsTo(internModel::class, 'InternId');

    if($withTrashed == true)
    {
        return $relation->withTrashed()->first();
    }

    return $relation->first();
}
```

But I wouldn't advise this because later on if you try using things like `WhereHas` you will get errors.  That said, another way would be to do something along the following lines:

```
public function intern()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(internModel::class, 'InternId');
}
```

Then get trashed like:

```
'MentorId' => $employee->intern()->withTrashed()->first()->mentor()->withTrashed()->first()->MentorId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below as per [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) guide. Keep in mind that parent model must have `hasOne/hasMany` method and child model must have `belongsTo` method.

**Intern**

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function intern($withTrashed = false)
{
    if($withTrashed == true)
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Intern', 'InternId')->withTrashed();
    }

    return $this->hasOne('App\Intern','InternId');
}
```

**Employee**

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function intern($withTrashed = false)
{
    if($withTrashed == true)
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Intern', 'InternId')->withTrashed();
    }

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Intern','InternId');
}
```

**Note:** Same for all other models.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Still receive the error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mentor()

Comment: @jamie if `Intern` is your parent class then use `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo`